# How do I change the Apple Watch notification timeout duration?

Tags: notifications, apple-watch

I find that a lot of the time I am not glancing at my watch to see the most recent notification in time. It feels like you only have 3 or 5 seconds to check, otherwise the watch defaults to showing the time.

I am asking if there is any possible way to adjust the duration that a notification stays visible for. Swiping it back to see requires the use of the second hand. Or the use of a nose. Or chin or tongue.

Previously I used a Pebble Time: As I recall, the notification is shown like on iOS, as a banner, so the time is still legible.

I believe that the following tweaks would be very helpful:

1. Configurable delay. I would prefer the notifications to stay visible for up to 10 seconds.
2. When notifications are visible, the time should be made visible in the corner or anywhere. This will mitigate the drawback of the longer notification visibility duration.